# subclassed label class is not key value coding-compliant

Tags: objective-c, subclass

**edit 1**

[This question is answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167479/where-are-the-labels-among-the-buttonshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167479/where-are-the-labels-among-the-buttons) Sorry for the  noise.

**edit 1**

**edit 0**

I have included more code below and also an image of the result which shows the result I get, which is the same result I got **without** the subclassing, with just plain labels. In the first 3 rows the labels seem to cover up the button altogether, and in the  4th row there are no labels, and notice that the button #2 is indented on the 4th row. What's going on.

This code only applies to the first of the four rows, but the other 3 rows are similar.

[image: buttons should go from A ... 2 in 4 rows with a spade symbol label between the buttons on the first row]

```
self.cardList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
self.yHonorsOrigin = 100;
self.xHonorsOrigin = 100;
self.xHonorsStep = 40.0;
self.xHonorsCurrent = self.xHonorsOrigin;
for( int x=0;x<[cards length]; x++ ){
    [cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)];
    UIButton *b= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    self.xHonorsCurrent += self.xHonorsStep;
    [b setTitle:[cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(self.xHonorsCurrent, self.yHonorsOrigin, 20, 20)];
    [b setEnabled:YES];
    [b setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(spadeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            self.xHonorsCurrent = self.xHonorsOrigin + self.xHonorsStep/2;
            for( int x=0;x<[cards length]-1; x++ ){
                self.xHonorsCurrent += self.xHonorsStep;
                UILabel *lab = [self valueForKey:@"theSuit" ];
                lab.text = @"\u2660";
                //lab.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                lab.center = CGPointMake(self.xHonorsCurrent, self.yHonorsOrigin);
                [self.view addSubview:lab];
            }
        }
    }
```

**edit 0**

I have attempted to subclass the UILabel class using `BDBoundedLabel`, but am throwing an exception that "subclassed label  class is not key value coding-compliant for the key `theSuit`." Please help.

BDBoundedLabel.m

```
#import "BDBoundedLabel.h"

@implementation BDBoundedLabel

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextStrokeRect(context, CGRectInset(self.bounds, 1, 1));
    [super drawTextInRect:CGRectInset(rect, 5.0, 5.0)];
}


@end
```

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BDViewController.h"
#import "BDBoundedLabel.h"

@interface BDnameViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet BDBoundedLabel* theSuit;
}
```

viewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.cardList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];
    self.yHonorsOrigin = 100;
    self.xHonorsOrigin = 100;
    self.xHonorsStep = 40.0;
    self.xHonorsCurrent = self.xHonorsOrigin;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.xHonorsCurrent = self.xHonorsOrigin + self.xHonorsStep/2;
        for( int x=0;x<[cards length]-1; x++ ){
            self.xHonorsCurrent += self.xHonorsStep;
            UILabel *lab = [BDBoundedLabel valueForKey:@"theSuit" ];
            lab.text = @"\u2660";
            lab.center = CGPointMake(self.xHonorsCurrent, self.yHonorsOrigin);
            [self.view addSubview:lab];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I cannot see from your code that `BDBoundedLabel` defines a property `theSuit` somewhere ...

Comment: Yes, please see my comment to the answer.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `BDBoundedLabel *lab = self.theSuit` ??

Comment: Did you mean `BDBoundedLabel *lab = self->theSuit;`? That does not produce an error, but does not change the resulting image (that is shown in the recent question EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

*setValue:forKey:* and *valueForKey:* will use the accessors methods (setter and getter), so you need to create them. Declare a property:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) BDBoundedLabel* theSuit;
```

Also, like stated by Benjamin you are calling *valueForKey:* on a class object, maybe you meant to call the method with *self* as target, this way:

```
UILabel *lab = [self valueForKey:@"theSuit" ];
// Equivalent of lab= self.theSuit
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting it. Where do I declare the property and do I leave the IBOutlet declaration in `Viewcontroller.h`?

Comment: Do I also need to something about the `setValue:forKey:`? Or what am I missing?

Comment: Like Benjamin says you're calling *valueForKey:* on a class object. Edited the answer. Let me know if after modifying the code it does what you want to do.

Comment: That does not produce an error, but does not change the resulting image (that is shown in the recent question EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not make any sense. You are performing KVO on a class object, which is almost never done. For most cases, KVO is only ever used on instances of a class, which is not what you are doing here.

Please try and clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to insert some single character labels between some single character buttons, so that the labels clarify the buttons. I think I will change to just make the labels background color clear, instead of making them skinnier like I was trying to do here, because this method is not working for me. When the labels are not adjusted in any way, they cover up the buttons, apparently.

Comment: I cannot find a property of UILabel which controls the background color so this approach is not working, either.