# where are the labels among the buttons

Tags: ios, uilabel

In the image below I am attempting to put a single-character label between each button, but as the second image shows, when I do insert the labels, the buttons disappear and (if you look closely) the last button's text moves to the right.

Can you help me get the desired result, please?

buttons without labels
[image: buttons without labels]

buttons with    labels
[image: buttons with labels]

ViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) UILabel* theSuit;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString* cards = @"AKQJT98765432";

    NSInteger yPipsOrigin = 100;
    NSInteger xPipsOrigin = 100;
    NSInteger xPipsStep = 40.0;
    NSInteger xPipsCurrent = xPipsOrigin;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    for( int x=0;x<[cards length]; x++ ){
        [cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)];
        UIButton *b= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        xPipsCurrent += xPipsStep;
        [b setTitle:[cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [b setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [b setFrame:CGRectMake(xPipsCurrent, yPipsOrigin, 20, 20)];
        [b setEnabled:YES];
        [b setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:b];
        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(spadeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        xPipsCurrent = xPipsOrigin + xPipsStep/2;
        for( int x=0;x<[cards length]-1; x++ ){
            xPipsCurrent += xPipsStep;
            UILabel *lab = self.theSuit;
            lab.text = @"Z";
            lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            lab.center = CGPointMake(xPipsCurrent, yPipsOrigin);
            [self.view addSubview:lab];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why have you added UILabel *lab = self.theSuit; as self.theSuit will be nil.

Comment: What do you recommend, please?

Comment: can u tell what exactly u want to achieve? i mean the final result. screenshot can be helpful.

Comment: `A Z K Z Q Z ... Z 2` is what I want. Well, really, I want the Z's to be unicodes "\u2660" . Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the below code. You can check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString* cards = @"AKQJT98765432";

NSInteger yPipsOrigin = 100;
NSInteger xPipsOrigin = 100;
NSInteger xPipsStep = 40.0;
NSInteger xPipsCurrent = xPipsOrigin;

for( int x=0;x<[cards length]; x++ )
{
    [cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)];
    UIButton *b= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    xPipsCurrent += xPipsStep;
    [b setTitle:[cards substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(x,1)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [b setFrame:CGRectMake(xPipsCurrent, yPipsOrigin, 20, 20)];
    [b setEnabled:YES];
    [b setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(spadeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UILabel *lab = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xPipsCurrent+b.frame.size.width, yPipsOrigin, 20, 20)];
    lab.text = @"Z";
    lab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:lab];
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is related to your comment that `self.theSuit` is nil, but there are no `Z`s showing here, either. How do I fix that?

Comment: i have edited the code. But i am not sure what exactly u want.

Comment: I finally see where my problem started: I put the second for-loop **inside** the first, instead of **after** the first, and never noticed the error. Of course, I also, could not remember the `init`. Duh. Thanks, again.